# Why are these strings not equal when uploaded on Lambda?

Tags: node.js, lambda

I am adding the string "references" into my Lambda function. However, for some reason when I try to see if the variable matches === "references" it returns a value of false. I've logged various values to make sure it is not being manipulated along the way. You can see what the cloud watch logs look like:

```
/*/Update an existing permissions request/*/
import handler from "./libs/handler-lib";
import dynamoDb from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";

export const main = handler(async (event, context) => {
    const data = event.body;
    //Set variables for update request depending on input:
    const setVariables = (eventData) => {
        console.log(`Event data equals data: ${data === eventData}\nEvent data: ${eventData}\nData: ${data}\nData equals "references": ${data === "references"}\nEvent Data equals "references": ${eventData === "references"}`);
        var expression;
        var body;
        var array;
        if (eventData === "references") {
            body = { ":referencesRequested": true };
            expression = "SET referencesRequested = :referencesRequested";
            array = [expression, body];
        } else if (eventData === "repos") {
            body = { ":hiddenreposRequested": true };
            expression = "SET hiddenreposRequested = :hiddenreposRequested";
            array = [expression, body];
        } else {
            body = { ":resumeRequested": true };
            expression = "SET resumeRequested = :resumeRequested";
            array = [expression, body];
        }
        return array;
    };

    const expression = setVariables(data)[0];
    const body = setVariables(data)[1];

    const params = {
        TableName: process.env.tableName,
        Key: {
            userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
            permissionsId: event.pathParameters.id
        },
        UpdateExpression: expression,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: body,
        ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
    };

    await dynamoDb.update(params);

    return { status: true };
});
```

[image]

Comment: Check the type of the `data` (it may not be a string), and also its `length` (might have whitespace characters?)

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance Yeah the type is a string (I checked) and I used the Trim method to ensure there was no whitespace. Still not equal. I'll go ahead and check the length, just in case.

Comment: Strange, maybe one of the characters is different. `[...data].forEach((char, i) => { if (char.charCodeAt() !== eventData.charCodeAt(i)) { /* log char codes and debug`

Comment: I just checked the length and data and Event data are a string length of 12 yet "references" is 10. Is almost as if the quotation marks are being counted.